# Getting data from the selected cell (TableView)

Tags: swift, swift3, tableview

I have a TableView with several cells of data and there are 3 labels in each cell.

How can I save all 3 label.text into another variable with indexPath

```
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

Here is the full code
I've actually asked in another post that the variable "limit" becomes null after the .observe thing.
So I'm thinking if I can get the data directly from the cell.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

struct limitStruct{
    var name : String!
    var today : String!
    var limit : String!

}

class CalcViewController: UITableViewController {

    var limits = [limitStruct]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.title = "Calculation"
        navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
            [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
        let databaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        databaseReference.child("Limit").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in
            var snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            let name = snapshotValue!["name"] as? String
            snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            let today = snapshotValue!["today"] as? String
            snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

            let limit = snapshotValue!["limit"] as? String
            snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary


            self.limits.insert(limitStruct(name:name, today:today, limit: limit), at: self.limits.count)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return limits.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Limit")

        let label1 = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = limits[indexPath.row].name

        let label2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = limits[indexPath.row].today

        let label3 = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        label3.text = limits[indexPath.row].limit

        return cell!
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetails"{

            let svc = segue.destination as! CirSliderViewController;

            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
//                svc.RsegueData =
            }




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you've written so far

Comment: And how did you put the infos in that cells? What's the code of `tableView(_tableView:cellForRowAt:)`? Did you set the texts from an array (dataSource)? Then since you retrieve the indexPath, just reed your array (dataSource)

Comment: @Larme I'm getting data from firebase. so it seems more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Could you show your code at least?

Comment: @Larme just did

Comment: `label2.text = limits[indexPath.row].today`, just do the same: `let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
; let myStringName = limits[indexPath.row].today;` I don't see your issue.

Comment: @Larme I'd like to pass these data to another ViewController

Comment: but the problem is when I do it in prepare for segue, the "limits" is null

Comment: This sounds strange. The limits array contains data when you run cellForRowAtIndexPath but not when you click on a cell and enter prepare for segue? Do you have any other code which manipulates the limits array?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to be using `viewWithTag()`. The best way to handle this is to subclass `UITableViewCell`, with a property for your data model object

```
class LimitCell: UITableViewCell {
   var limit: Limit {
       didSet {
           // configureCell()
       }
    }
}
```

Then in your view controller:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Limit", forIndex: indexPath) as! LimitCell
   cell.limit = limits[indexPath.row]
   return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let svc = segue.destination as? CirSliderViewController, cell = sender as? LimitCell {
        svc.RsegueData = cell.limit
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are using a callback to get the data. Does the data come from a server or is stored locally?

1) If the data comes from a server, you code cannot guarantee that `var limits` already got the data when the `func prepare` is called.

2) If the data is stored locally, and ONLY `limit`is nil, you must check whether or not you correctly assign `limits[indexPath.row].limit` to `limits` to the cell.(Is it nil at this moment?) I think the problem is in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` where `limit` is saved.

By the way, the more practical and efficient way to implement  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is that:

Lets say the your custom cell is call `LimitCell` and has three UILabels: `var label1`, `var label2`, `var label3`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Limit") as! LimitCell

    cell.label1.text = limits[indexPath.row].name
    cell.label2.text = limits[indexPath.row].today
    cell.label3.text = limits[indexPath.row].limit

    return cell
}
```